# test_venv failed Python 3.6.1 install

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pip

I've just installed Linux Mint 18.1 (so I'm new to Linux and I don't know what I'm doing!) and I'm attempting to install Python 3.6.1.
However, one of the install tests keeps failing--test_venv.
Here's the log:

```
running build
running build_ext
INFO: Can't locate Tcl/Tk libs and/or headers
warning: building with the bundled copy of libffi is deprecated on this platform.  It will not be distributed with Python 3.7

Python build finished successfully!
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_bz2                  _curses               _curses_panel      
_dbm                  _gdbm                 _lzma              
_sqlite3              _ssl                  _tkinter           
readline              zlib                                     
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.

The following modules found by detect_modules() in setup.py, have been
built by the Makefile instead, as configured by the Setup files:
atexit                pwd                   time               
running build_scripts
copying and adjusting /opt/Python-3.6.1/Tools/scripts/pydoc3 -> build/scripts-3.6
copying and adjusting /opt/Python-3.6.1/Tools/scripts/idle3 -> build/scripts-3.6
copying and adjusting /opt/Python-3.6.1/Tools/scripts/2to3 -> build/scripts-3.6
copying and adjusting /opt/Python-3.6.1/Tools/scripts/pyvenv -> build/scripts-3.6
changing mode of build/scripts-3.6/pydoc3 from 644 to 755
changing mode of build/scripts-3.6/idle3 from 644 to 755
changing mode of build/scripts-3.6/2to3 from 644 to 755
changing mode of build/scripts-3.6/pyvenv from 644 to 755
renaming build/scripts-3.6/pydoc3 to build/scripts-3.6/pydoc3.6
renaming build/scripts-3.6/idle3 to build/scripts-3.6/idle3.6
renaming build/scripts-3.6/2to3 to build/scripts-3.6/2to3-3.6
renaming build/scripts-3.6/pyvenv to build/scripts-3.6/pyvenv-3.6
./python  ./Tools/scripts/run_tests.py -v test_venv
/opt/Python-3.6.1/python -W default -bb -E -W error::BytesWarning -m test -r -w -j 0 -u all,-largefile,-audio,-gui -v test_venv
== CPython 3.6.1 (default, Apr 16 2017, 09:33:09) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
==   Linux-4.4.0-53-generic-i686-athlon-with-debian-stretch-sid little-endian
==   hash algorithm: siphash24 32bit
==  cwd: /opt/Python-3.6.1/build/test_python_21688
==  encodings: locale=UTF-8, FS=utf-8
Testing with flags: sys.flags(debug=0, inspect=0, interactive=0, optimize=0, dont_write_bytecode=0, no_user_site=0, no_site=0, ignore_environment=1, verbose=0, bytes_warning=2, quiet=0, hash_randomization=1, isolated=0)
Using random seed 8896684
Run tests in parallel using 4 child processes
0:00:03 [1/1/1] test_venv failed
test_defaults (test.test_venv.BasicTest) ... ok
test_executable (test.test_venv.BasicTest) ... ok
test_executable_symlinks (test.test_venv.BasicTest) ... ok
test_isolation (test.test_venv.BasicTest) ... ok
test_overwrite_existing (test.test_venv.BasicTest) ... ok
test_prefixes (test.test_venv.BasicTest) ... ok
test_prompt (test.test_venv.BasicTest) ... ok
test_symlinking (test.test_venv.BasicTest) ... ok
test_unoverwritable_fails (test.test_venv.BasicTest) ... ok
test_upgrade (test.test_venv.BasicTest) ... ok
test_devnull (test.test_venv.EnsurePipTest) ... ok
test_explicit_no_pip (test.test_venv.EnsurePipTest) ... ok
test_no_pip_by_default (test.test_venv.EnsurePipTest) ... ok
test_with_pip (test.test_venv.EnsurePipTest) ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: test_with_pip (test.test_venv.EnsurePipTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/Python-3.6.1/Lib/test/test_venv.py", line 368, in do_test_with_pip
    with_pip=True)
  File "/opt/Python-3.6.1/Lib/test/test_venv.py", line 61, in run_with_capture
    func(*args, **kwargs)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/tmp/tmp75p27d_d/bin/python', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/Python-3.6.1/Lib/test/test_venv.py", line 428, in test_with_pip
    self.do_test_with_pip(False)
  File "/opt/Python-3.6.1/Lib/test/test_venv.py", line 374, in do_test_with_pip
    self.fail(msg.format(exc, details))
AssertionError: Command '['/tmp/tmp75p27d_d/bin/python', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

**Subprocess Output**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/Python-3.6.1/Lib/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/opt/Python-3.6.1/Lib/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/opt/Python-3.6.1/Lib/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    ensurepip._main()
  File "/opt/Python-3.6.1/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 189, in _main
    default_pip=args.default_pip,
  File "/opt/Python-3.6.1/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 102, in bootstrap
    _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
  File "/opt/Python-3.6.1/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 27, in _run_pip
    import pip
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 14 tests in 2.668s

FAILED (failures=1)
test test_venv failed

1 test failed:
    test_venv
Re-running failed tests in verbose mode
Re-running test 'test_venv' in verbose mode
test_defaults (test.test_venv.BasicTest) ... ok
test_executable (test.test_venv.BasicTest) ... ok
test_executable_symlinks (test.test_venv.BasicTest) ... ok
test_isolation (test.test_venv.BasicTest) ... ok
test_overwrite_existing (test.test_venv.BasicTest) ... ok
test_prefixes (test.test_venv.BasicTest) ... ok
test_prompt (test.test_venv.BasicTest) ... ok
test_symlinking (test.test_venv.BasicTest) ... ok
test_unoverwritable_fails (test.test_venv.BasicTest) ... ok
test_upgrade (test.test_venv.BasicTest) ... ok
test_devnull (test.test_venv.EnsurePipTest) ... ok
test_explicit_no_pip (test.test_venv.EnsurePipTest) ... ok
test_no_pip_by_default (test.test_venv.EnsurePipTest) ... ok
test_with_pip (test.test_venv.EnsurePipTest) ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: test_with_pip (test.test_venv.EnsurePipTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/Python-3.6.1/Lib/test/test_venv.py", line 368, in do_test_with_pip
    with_pip=True)
  File "/opt/Python-3.6.1/Lib/test/test_venv.py", line 61, in run_with_capture
    func(*args, **kwargs)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/tmp/tmp0zy9q1i8/bin/python', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/Python-3.6.1/Lib/test/test_venv.py", line 428, in test_with_pip
    self.do_test_with_pip(False)
  File "/opt/Python-3.6.1/Lib/test/test_venv.py", line 374, in do_test_with_pip
    self.fail(msg.format(exc, details))
AssertionError: Command '['/tmp/tmp0zy9q1i8/bin/python', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

**Subprocess Output**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/Python-3.6.1/Lib/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/opt/Python-3.6.1/Lib/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/opt/Python-3.6.1/Lib/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    ensurepip._main()
  File "/opt/Python-3.6.1/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 189, in _main
    default_pip=args.default_pip,
  File "/opt/Python-3.6.1/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 102, in bootstrap
    _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
  File "/opt/Python-3.6.1/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 27, in _run_pip
    import pip
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 14 tests in 2.652s

FAILED (failures=1)
test test_venv failed
1 test failed again:
    test_venv

Total duration: 6 sec
Tests result: FAILURE
Makefile:1018: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

There's a few things that may be going wrong--at the top it mentions the optional modules that were not found, but I can't figure out how to fix them. I tried installing them with pip, but I got more errors. I also tried looking in detect_modles() in setup.py, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do from there. Any pointers on where to go next?

Comment: I meet the same problem and notice the output:
[zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291737/zipimport-zipimporterror-cant-decompress-data-zlib-not-available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also on Linux Mint 18.1 (Cinnamon) and had similar/same issues installing Python 3.6.0 from source.

> Installation of Python from source requires C++ header files of other non-Python modules having nothing to do with Python.

So first install one after another the missing modules (mentioned in the log-file) using the Synaptic Package Manager AND consider that you need the **DEV** files for them too, so for each module install both, the module and the **-dev variant of the module**.

That should be enough for a successful compilation as I have in my notes about it only:

`Sucessfully built according to with the source provided instructions :)`

what usually means that there were no other problems as these ones about which you can read from the log-file and the instructions given in the readme or at the site providing the download and installation instructions.

I suggest you follow the advice given in the log-file:

> **To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.**

So look there for the modules name and the search for it in the **Synaptic Package Manager** and mark it for installation and then push the [Apply] button there to install them (don't forget about -dev version)
Linux Mint 18.1 comes with Python 3.5 , so you may ask yourself if you really need the 3.6 version of Python? Maybe you can live with 3.5 and install it via Synaptic Package Manager as Python 3 ?

By the way: if you are really not knowing what you are doing I don't know if it is possible to help you ...

Here a hint for installation of ncurses: 
[image]

and readline:

[image]

Finally after you are done with building and testing take care that you install Python 3.6.1 using

> make **altinstall**

in order to preserve the standard Python versions already existing on the system.

Comment: Oh sweet, it already has 3.5? I only saw 2.7 on it, and I only need some form of 3. Thanks so much!

Comment: Think I have now--sorry, new to StackOverflow! Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome :) . By the way: somewhere in the "rules" here is stated that you should avoid to say "thank you" in the comments as this is not helpful for all others reading them. Just mark an answer as accepted or vote it up (both expresses "thank you"). The comments are here to cover the case that something is still unclear. To be kind does not belong here the same way how being rude doesn't.